# How to draw Borders for Custom Views in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, border

I have created a **CustomView class extending from the ViewGroup**. My Idea is to arrange these CustomViews like cells in a table. I have added a **TextBlock as child for each CustomViews** and have a variable index to maintain the index of the cell in the table. My ***requirement is to draw the right and bottom borders for the CustomViews*** such that it appear like a table. I tried creating an xml drawable such as /res/drawable/textlines.xml and assigned it as my CustomView's background property.

Here is the code that I tried. But this draws borders on all four sides. However I need only right and bottom borders alone. Is there any other way to achieve this?

```
<item android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/black" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Please do not recommend making the left and top borders as negative values. I believe its not the correct way to achieve this requirement. Please suggest me some workarounds to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have a custom view you can override onDraw and draw line there. Here's an example:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor( Color.RED );
    paint.setStrokeWidth( 1.5f );
    paint.setStyle( Paint.Style.STROKE );
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a border to which side you want,
In addition, you can control various parameters of each side, for example color or thickness of the border.
An example for adding a border to the right and botoom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
  <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
  </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="1dp">
  <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFDDDDDD" />
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
  </shape>
</item>

  <item android:bottom="1dp"> 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFDDDDDD" />
        <solid android:color="#00000000" />
     </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```